# Jquery Tabs: Accessing non default tab with url

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I am using jquery tabs to create 3 tabs and following is my html code

```
    <div id="sections" class="sections">
      <ul class="sections" role="tablist">
        <li class="active" role="presentation">
          <a href="#user" aria-controls="user" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">User</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation">
          <a href="#setting" aria-controls="setting" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Setting</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation">
          <a href="#customer" aria-controls="customer" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Customer</a>
        </li>           
      </ul>

      <div class="tab-content">
        <section id="user" class="panel" role="tabpanel">
            Some content is here
        </section>

        <section id="setting" class="panel" role="tabpanel">
            Some content is here
        </section>

        <section id="customer" class="panel" role="tabpanel">
            Some content is here
        </section>
      </div>
```

And initilizing the tabs like

$('#sections').tabs();

Now when I access the page with /#setting at url end it briefly opens User Tab first before showing the Setting tab. How can I avoid this?

Comment: Hide the section, initialize the tabs, show the section.

Comment: Can parse url hash and set active yourself based on hash when you initialize

Comment: Even if i remove "active" from class and write $('#sections').tabs( "option", "active", 1 ); it still opens the first tab for a moment before going to second.